# Shape detection aftr object detection to get precise bounding box

Tags: opencv, localization, object-detection, yolo, edge-detection

I'm working on a project where I want to get height of object in image.
I'm able to identify the object and get bounding box using object detection but the box is not precise(little bigger). Can I crop the image with bounding box coordinates and then apply some mechanism like edge detection or something to get exact bounding box or height.
Since semantic segmentation is heavier I don't wanna go ahead with that also my trained models are in yolo.[image][image]

Edit: Added pic with the object detected- object is stop sign as u can see the bounding box is little bigger with respect to height..

Comment: I think you can't account for deep learning object detection to perform measurement.... you'll need another step. you can post your image with the bounding box  as well

Comment: There is a problem with this task, which is that you don't necessarily know what the object boundaries are. In this case you might consider the edges of the red area, because the dominant color is red, but in other cases it can be much more tricky. You may try some form of color segmentation, pick the largest region, and pray.